# Stack Overflow blog : same post with different languages in the search result

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, blog

While conducting a search on the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) using the keyword "Winter Bash 2017", I observed the presence of three posts sharing an identical title. Upon examining each post, it became evident that they were composed in different languages Português, Español, and English.
To improve the search experience, could the results be refined to display only one post for the specified search title?

**Screenshot of search result with the blog post URL:**

[image: One keyword - three results]

Comment: The search itself is terrible, that's a major downgrade of the UX. Having it limited to that small textbox instead of actual search results page renders the search useless, at least for me. All in all, they made the blog pretty, while taking away great many features. So this specific bug is pretty minor, IMO.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard I'm sorry you feel like we've taken away great features. For this first launch we wanted an minimum viable product that we will keep iterating, I agree there is absolutely more work to do with search. Thanks for all the great feedback so far in other threads too. Keep it coming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've renamed these posts with the language appended to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks. What about the `<strike>Hits</strike>`? Is this some pun, or should it be actually with strike-through line?